# Infinity symbol does not show in Matlab plot

Tags: matlab, latex, tex, axis-labels, infinity

I'm trying to include the infinity symbol `∞` in my axis label (*e.g.* the expression `δ∞`), so I typed `\delta_{\infty}`. However, I only see the delta symbol `δ` but the infinity symbol is portrayed as a subscripted black diamond with a question mark inside.

The interpreter is set to Tex and I tried different fonts with other symbols. The greek letters seem to be working but other symbols like `\clubsuit` (`♣`) don't. Do I need to make any other changes to the settings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From this I make up that you should use LaTeX as the interpreter, rather than TeX:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/21984

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I set the interpreter to latex. However, I only got the warning: Warning: Unable to interpret LaTeX string "\delta_{\infty}", and the axis plot is not shown.

Comment: How about using math mode?
http://www.adras.com/Unable-to-interpret-TeX-string.t123345-80.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're still looking for answer, it works for you: `\delta_\infty = δ∞`